# Interpretation of PTP4L and PHC2SYS syslog records

Tags: centos, ntp, real-time

I'm using the *ptp4l* and *phc4sys* services to syncronize the clocks of my Centos 7.4 servers to a central PTP source. The services regularly write syslog records like the one below.
I haven't found any documentation explaining what each field here means, and what the units are. I'd appreciate any leads!

```
Nov 14 17:07:26 stg1 ptp4l: [718277.895] rms   74 max   99 freq  +8760 +/-  84 delay   535 +/-   0
Nov 14 17:07:27 stg1 phc2sys: [718278.105] phc offset       -62 s2 freq  +14460 delay   2117
```

Comment: Does [this Github repo](https://github.com/richardcochran/linuxptp) seem to be up-to-date with the version you're using?

Comment: Yes! It has a tag for v1.8 which comes with my CentOS 7. Thanks for finding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through the file `print.c`, I found the following snippet in the "print" function:

```
if (use_syslog) {
    syslog(level, "[%ld.%03ld] %s%s%s",
           ts.tv_sec, ts.tv_nsec / 1000000,
           message_tag ? message_tag : "", message_tag ? " " : "",
           buf);
}
```

`print.h` defines more macros using this function. Some seem unused, and others relate to errors not present in your example, but the macro `pr_info` is called at one point in `clock.c` in a way that could account for those logs:

```
if (!stats_get_result(s->delay, &delay_stats)) {
    pr_info("rms %4.0f max %4.0f "
        "freq %+6.0f +/- %3.0f "
        "delay %5.0f +/- %3.0f",
        offset_stats.rms, offset_stats.max_abs,
        freq_stats.mean, freq_stats.stddev,
        delay_stats.mean, delay_stats.stddev);
} else {
    pr_info("rms %4.0f max %4.0f "
        "freq %+6.0f +/- %3.0f",
        offset_stats.rms, offset_stats.max_abs,
        freq_stats.mean, freq_stats.stddev);
}
```

I don't know much about PTP4L, but hopefully those variable names point you on the right track. If you want to explore further, [here](https://github.com/richardcochran/linuxptp) is the github repository.

Answer (score 2):

I got below explanation from another link:

The values are in nanoseconds:

The master offset value represents the measured offset from the master (in nanoseconds).

The s0, s1, s2 indicators show the different states of the clock servo: s0 is unlocked, s1 is clock step, and s2 is locked. If the servo is in the locked state (s2), the clock will not be stepped (only slowly adjusted) if the pi_offset_const option is set to a negative value in the configuration file (see man 8 ptp4l for more information).

The freq value represents the frequency adjustment of the clock (in parts per billion, ppb).

The path delay value represents the estimated delay of the synchronization messages sent from the master (in nanoseconds).

Port 0 is a Unix domain socket used for local PTP management. Port 1 is the eth0 interface.

INITIALIZING, LISTENING, UNCALIBRATED and SLAVE are examples of port states which change on INITIALIZE, RS_SLAVE, and MASTER_CLOCK_SELECTED events. When the port state changes from UNCALIBRATED to SLAVE, the computer has successfully synchronized with a PTP master clock.